# getting unique date from python dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has dates in format:
dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss

E.g

```
15-14-2016 08:05:10 
15-14-2016 08:15:30 
15-14-2016 10:45:22 
18-14-2016 06:23:10 
18-14-2016 07:37:30 
18-14-2016 12:48:22
```

There are around 1000 rows and

I used below code to get unique dates

```
print pd.unique((df.Date).dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y'))
```

but my output seems to be 2 lists instead of just one:

```
['15-04-16' '18-04-16' '19-04-16' '20-04-16' '21-04-16' '22-04-16']    
['15-04-16' '18-04-16' '19-04-16' '20-04-16' '21-04-16' '22-04-16']
```

Can anyone help

Comment: What imports are you using? What are 'pd' and 'df'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use  [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with [`unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) if you need convert `dates` to `strings`:

```
print df

                 Date
0 2016-12-15 08:05:10
1 2016-12-15 08:15:30
2 2016-12-15 10:45:22
3 2016-12-18 06:23:10
4 2016-12-18 07:37:30
5 2016-12-18 12:48:22

#if dtype of column date Date is not datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])    

print df.Date.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y').unique()
['15-12-16' '18-12-16']
```

If you need unique `dates`, use [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
print df.Date.dt.date.unique()
[datetime.date(2016, 12, 15) datetime.date(2016, 12, 18)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy.unique:

```
import numpy as np

df
Out[20]: 
                 date
0 2016-04-15 08:05:10
1 2016-04-15 08:15:30
2 2016-04-15 10:45:22
3 2016-04-18 06:23:10
4 2016-04-18 07:37:30
5 2016-04-18 12:48:22
6 2016-04-18 12:48:22


np.unique(df["date"].dt.strftime('%d-%m-%y'))
Out[22]: array(['15-04-16', '18-04-16'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.Date.normalize().unique()
```

might work as well.

Also in case where your index type is datetime, this can be used as:

```
unique_dates = df.index.normalize().nunique()
```